# Selenium Chrome Driver - Clicks and scrolls do not work when window is in background

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am running Selenium (v3.141.0) on Python 3. I have a sequence of element clicks and element scrolls which work flawlessly when the browser (Chrome) window is in focus. These however stop working completely when the Chrome window is in the background.

I am hooking Selenium to a manually opened browser window, specifically open for debugging. I also tried passing the `--headless` parameter to the driver options, with no luck.

Is this an inherent limitation to Selenium, do I need to keep the window in focus while the program is running, or can this be achieved successfully while the window is in the background, and I am attending to other tasks?

Comment: Unless you show your code who knows what is going on? Read [mcve] and [tour] then edit your post accodringly.

Comment: I have clicks working using Selenium in a C# console program with the Chrome window in background. However, Selenium shares the "real" mouse, so if your Selenium code sets or relies on mouse position, your manual mouse actions can conflict with that. Don't know if that could be your problem.

Comment: Your mouse shouldn't have any effect at all.... Selenium would automate the "pointer" which isn't actually the mouse you are controlling manually.    There are times when I've seen the browser move itself into focus during tests... but I've never seen it interrupted because of being in the background or even minimized.  It is possible for a web site to detect if the window is visible, though:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API  That might affect things, or it could be something about how you are running the script and/or the IDE debugging it.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this code to create your chrome driver.**
**This will run in headless mode without any interference.**
Plus now you don't have to keep the window open when the script is running since this codebase will run in the background and you can do whatever you want on your screen.

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

class ChromeDriver_Class(webdriver.Chrome):
    def __init__(self, chrome_driver_path, teardown=False):
        self.driver_path = chrome_driver_path

        self.options = Options()
        self.options.headless = True
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=self.driver_path,options=self.options)
    
        self.options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
        self.options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')

        self.teardown = teardown
        os.environ['PATH'] += self.driver_path
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.driver.maximize_window()
```